# Keep getting stuck loading when ScrapySharp NavigateToPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, scrapysharp

My browser just keeps loading when navigatetopage using scrapysharp and won't go to the next line of code. Below is my code using c# asp.net web form. May I know why? The link I use is working and can manually browse. The code just gets stuck at the `Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("http://www.asnb.com.my/v3_/asnbv2_0index.php"));` and keep loading in the browser. And I am using asp.net webform.

```
ScrapingBrowser Browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
Browser.AllowAutoRedirect = true; 
Browser.AllowMetaRedirect = true;

WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("http://www.asnb.com.my/v3_/asnbv2_0index.php"));
HtmlNode TitleNode = PageResult.Html.CssSelect(".navbar-brand").First();
```

Comment: Its so weird... I have older projects where I use ScrapySharp and they are still running fine. No hang/stuck at NavigateToPage. But I try ScrapySharp in a new MVC project (with same targeted framework and version) and it get stuck at NavigateToPage...
Anyway HtmlAgilityPack works fine in new projects - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/web-scraping-in-c-sharp/

Comment: @NickG. I also had previously running code hanging when moving it from a console project to a WPF project. Fixed with [DaBlue solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157018/774575)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and decided not to use `Browser.NavigateToPage` and instead get the `PageResult.Html`using an `HtmlDocument`.

For example:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.asnb.com.my/v3_/asnbv2_0index.php");
HtmlNode TitleNode = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".navbar-brand").First();
```

This should get you your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Move your call to a backgroundworker thread.  Notice that in line 353 in ScrapingBrowser.cs (ScrapySharp/ScrapySharp/Network/ScrapingBrowser.cs), the call to NavigateToPage() calls the Async version:

```
public WebPage NavigateToPage(Uri url, HttpVerb verb = HttpVerb.Get, string data = "", string contentType = null)
{
  return NavigateToPageAsync(url, verb, data, contentType).Result;
}
```

I had the same problem, as soon as I moved the call to my DoWork method in my BGW thread, it starts behaving the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use the async version of the NavigateToPage eg:

```
private async Task<WebPage> LoadPage(Uri uri)
{
    WebPage page = await browser.NavigateToPageAsync(uri);
    return page;
}
```

Comment: I moved a piece of working code from a Console application to a WPF application, and the call using `NavigateToPage` stopped working. This solution fixed it.